# Accessing API with $http POST Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: angularjs, rest, post, angular-http

I am trying to access this REST API, which accepts three parameters:
`stationId`, `crusherId`, `monthYear`
I am doing it like this in AngularJS as:

```
$http({
        //headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
        //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 
            'Accept':       'application/json'
        },
        url:    'https://myurl../api/getHPData',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            stationId: 263, 
            crusherId: 27, 
            monthYear: '2016-4'
        }
    })

    .then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            console.log(data);
     })
    .catch(function(error){
            //console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            console.log(error);
        })
```

But I am always getting this:

> Object {data: "{"result":"false"}", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK", headers: function}

OR

> {"data":"{\"result\":\"false\"}","status":200,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"headers":{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8","Accept":"application/json"},"url":"https://myurl../api/getHPData","data":{"stationId":263,"crusherId":27,"monthYear":"2016-4"}},"statusText":"OK"}

If I change `header` `Content-Type` to:

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
```

It gives:

> Object {data: null, status: -1, config: Object, statusText: "",headers: function}

OR

> {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json;
>   charset=UTF-8","Accept":"application/json, text/plain,
>   */*"},"url":"https://myurl../api/getHPData","data":{"stationId":263,"crusherId":27,"monthYear":"2016-4"}},"statusText":""}

What I am doing wrong, Please help me.

Plunker is here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/57SiCdBZB2OkhdR03VOs?p=preview

(Edit)

**Note:**
I can do it in `jQuery` as:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        get_homepage_data(263, 27, '2016-04');

        function get_homepage_data(stationIds, crusherIds, date) {
            var url = "https://myurl../api/getHPData";
            var data_to_send = {
                'stationId': stationIds, 
                'crusherId': crusherIds,
                'monthYear': date
            };

            console.log("Value is: " + JSON.stringify(data_to_send));
            //change sender name with account holder name
            //        console.log(data_to_send)
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method:   'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                //contentType: 'application/json',
                data: data_to_send,
                processData: true,
                // crossDomain: true,
                beforeSend: function () {
                }
                , complete: function () {}
                , success: function (result1) {
                    var Result = JSON.parse(result1);
                    var value_data = Result["valueResult"];
                    var foo = value_data["gyydt"];

                    console.log("Log of foo is: " + foo);

                    var foo2 = 0;
                    // 10 lac is one million.
                    foo2 = foo / 1000000 + ' million';

                    console.log(JSON.stringify(value_data["gyydt"]) + " in million is: " + foo2);
                }
                , error: function (request, error) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }   
    }); // eof Document. Ready  
</script>
```

Output of above script is `script` is:

- Value is: {"stationId":263,"crusherId":27,"monthYear":"2016-04"}
- XHR finished loading: POST
  "https://myurl../api/getHPData".
- Log of foo is: 26862094
- "26862094" in million is: 26.862094 million

Which is perfect. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When posting form data that is URL encoded, transform the request with the [$httpParamSerializer service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer):

```
$http({
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
    url: 'https://fnrc.gov.ae/roayaservices/api/getHPData',
    method: 'POST',
    transformRequest: $httpParamSerializer,
    transformResponse: function (x) {
      return angular.fromJson(angular.fromJson(x));
    },
    data: {
      "stationId": 263,
      "crusherId": 27,
      "monthYear": '2016-04'
    }
}) 
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    $scope.res = response.data;
    console.log($scope.res);
});
```

Normally the $http service automatically parses the results from a JSON encoded object but this API is returning a string that has been doubly serialized from an object. The `transformResponse` function fixes that problem.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/1ckQdZvkYAahtFmJtzbL?p=preview)

Comment: Hello. Thank You for your answer. It is working now. Whao. :) But can you please tell me: `How would I know that I will be using: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and how will I know that the `string` is doubly serialized. Can you please add some more details? So that it can help me in future as well. Thank You

Comment: I will be needing: value of `gytotal` which is inside: `valueResult`, Can you please give me some idea how to do it?

Comment: `parseFloat(response.data.valueResult.gytotal)`

Comment: This could be helpful. But, I am on an older version of AngularJS (1.2.21). Where '$httpParamSerializer' is not available.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://fnrc.gov.ae/roayaservices/Help/Api/POST-api-getHPData) says that the stationId and crusherId parameters should be arrays of strings.  Also, it looks like you are sending JSON data, so make sure to set that header correctly.

```
$http({
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'Accept':       'application/json'
    },
    url:    'https://fnrc.gov.ae/roayaservices/api/getHPData',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        stationId: ['263'], 
        crusherId: ['27'], 
        monthYear: '2016-4'
    }
})
```

When I change the code in your plunkr to use the corrected code above, I get the following response: "*The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'.*"

As the other (now deleted) answer correctly mentioned, this means that there is a CORS issue.  The browser is trying to send a "preflight" request before making the cross-origin request, and the server doesn't know what to do with it.  You can also see this message in the Chrome console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://fnrc.gov.ae/roayaservices/api/getHPData. Response for
>   preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Comment: Not working, I tried this as well and it return: `{"data":"{\"result\":\"false\"}","status":200,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"headers":{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8","Accept":"application/json"},"url":"https://fnrc.gov.ae/roayaservices/api/getHPData","data":{"stationId":[263],"crusherId":[27],"monthYear":"2016-4"}},"statusText":"OK"}`

Comment: @fWd82 since you are sending JSON, you should also set your content-type to JSON.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank You for updating your answer, it's still giving me the same error. Note that this error is coming from `.catch(function(error)`. I don't know what to do. Can you please see the Plnkr link I included in my question?

Comment: @fWd82 When I change your plunkr to use the code above, I get this error: "{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'."}" Which means that the other answerer was correct, there is a CORS issue.  Chrome is trying to make a "preflight" request to allow CORS, but the server doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: Hello Thank You for edit and looking into plnkr. I installed `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *` from [Google Chrome Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) and it working. When I edit my plnkr to changes you suggest I still see this: `config: Objectdata: "{"result":"false"}"headers: function (d)status: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object`

Comment: @fWd82 If that's the case, could it be that your parameter values are not correct?  Like, you're getting no results from the API?

Comment: I have verified all the values [Here](http://wst.mytechlabs.com/) as `stationId: 263, crusherId: 27, monthYear: '2016-4' `

Comment: @fWd82 Unfortunately, I don't think I can be much more help.  It looks like you are conforming to the API, so I can't imagine why it would return "false" (and the meaning behind the responses is not well-specified in that documentation).  Good luck to you, sorry I couldn't be more help!

Comment: Thank You for your time. `+1` for documentation link, and other helpful stuff. :)

Comment: @fWd82 Thanks!  I'm glad someone was able to help you out.